# Redirect certain pages if user logged in

Tags: redirect, login

how would one go about redirect certain pages if the user viewing them is logged into the WordPress CMS? For example, we have 2 registration pages that when logged in should direct to some other page / category archive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$location = The absolute URI to which the user will be redirected. No default.
$status = The status code to use. For example, 301, 302, etc. The default is 302.
You can use template tags for the $location parameter, for example:

```
<?php // redirect to the home page
wp_redirect(home_url()); exit; ?>

<?php wp_redirect('http://example.com/', 301); exit; ?>
```

If user is logged in

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in() ) {
wp_redirect ( home_url("/pagename") );
exit;
}
?>
```